# Stored procedure dynamic T-SQL query not working properly

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and have run into an issue with my dynamic T-SQL query. I believe it has to do with my syntax however it runs in a new query window fine when taken out of the dynamic T-SQL context. When ran as a stored procedure I sometimes get the following error:

> *Column `dbo.Birds.weight` is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY`
>   clause.*

T-SQL code:

```
set @sql =
N'select FLOOR(dbo.Birds.weight * @INPUTconversion)*@INPUTinterval as ''Weight'',
COUNT(1) as ''Count''
FROM dbo.Birds
WHERE
weight >= @INPUTminwgt AND 
weight <= @INPUTmaxwgt
GROUP BY FLOOR(weight*@INPUTconversion) 
order by weight asc'


set @params =
N'@INPUTminwgt float, 
@INPUTmaxwgt float, 
@INPUTconversion float,
@INPUTinterval float';

exec sp_executesql @sql, @params,  
@INPUTminwgt = @BirdMinWeight, 
@INPUTmaxwgt = @BirdMaxWeight,
@INPUTconversion = @conversion,
@INPUTinterval = @interval;
```

The weights are go to the 1000 decimal place (e.g. 3.154)

```
@INPUTconversion = 1/interval
```

The query should return weights between the min and max weight parameters, grouped by the the interval (e.g. .1 intervals would be like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 with the counts of the total birds in that weight span)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: did you try GROUP BY FLOOR(dbo.Birds.weight*@INPUTconversion) ?

Comment: In the group by, I think `*@INPUTinterval` is missing. It should be `FLOOR(dbo.Birds.weight * @INPUTconversion)*@INPUTinterval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the group by, `*@INPUTintervals` is missing.

It should be `GROUP BY FLOOR(dbo.Birds.weight * @INPUTconversion)*@INPUTinterval`

Also,you can't use the alias `weight` in your `where` and `order by`, you have to use `FLOOR(dbo.Birds.weight * @INPUTconversion)*@INPUTinterval` or `dbo.Birds.weight` cause here it's ambiguous which one you need.

```
set @sql =
N'select FLOOR(dbo.Birds.weight * @INPUTconversion)*@INPUTinterval as ''Weight'',
COUNT(1) as ''Count''
FROM dbo.Birds
WHERE
dbo.Birds.weight >= @INPUTminwgt AND 
dbo.Birds.weight <= @INPUTmaxwgt
GROUP BY FLOOR(weight*@INPUTconversion) *@INPUTinterval
order by FLOOR(weight*@INPUTconversion) *@INPUTinterval asc'
```

Comment: Now its working its like a miracle.  I tried using dbo.Birds.weight and went back and forth between using just "weight" before posting this question. With dbo.Birds.weight and adding the *@INPUTinterval it seems to have fixed it thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's not quite recognizing that dbo.Birds.Weight is the same thing as "weight" at the bottom of your query.  This is certainly interesting, and I don't know quite *why* this is happening, but this will probably work:

```
set @sql = N'
SELECT 
  FLOOR(b.weight * @INPUTconversion) * @INPUTinterval as [Weight],
  COUNT(*) as ''Count''
FROM  dbo.Birds b
WHERE b.weight >= @INPUTminwgt 
AND   b.weight <= @INPUTmaxwgt
GROUP BY FLOOR(b.weight * @INPUTconversion) * @INPUTinterval
ORDER BY FLOOR(b.weight * @INPUTconversion) * @INPUTinterval'
```